# How to type a map function that receives different types of arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have created the following function and I need to type the `i` argument that is currently an `any`:

1. scenario - with value and label

[image]

2. scenario - with id and name

[image]

3. scenario - without extra properties
   [image]

And my main problem is that I can receive an array that has different property names, like:

```
const status: {
    status: number;
    label: string;
}[],
const departments: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}[]
```

so my  `i` sometimes can be status and label but can also be id and name. So how to properly type this `i`? I tried using unknown but I get this message:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try set `i` to both types instead of `any`:

```
const handleMap = (arr: Array<unknown>, filterValue?: string, filterLabel?: string) => {
    return arr
        ? arr.map((i: status | departments) => ({
                value: i.toString(),
                label: i,
          }))
        : [];
};
```

Comment: I have updated the question with 3 code examples, can you take a look?

Comment: @ncesar Could you share the code itself without using picture?